# Voltage DAC, overcome settling time in a corner case

Tags: dac

I need a (relatively) cheap DAC to produce a ramp voltage with a update rate of ~1uS per step. Since fully specified 1uS settling voltage DACs are quite expensive, I investigate  the possibility to use a little slower device, like ~5uS as DACx0501.

In addition REF and BUFF are included.

http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/DAC60501

This is based on the fact that:

**Settling time** is specified from 1/4 to 3/4 full scale. I need to settle from one LSB to another (up or down) and according this fig. of datasheet (glitch impulse), I should be fine, about 1uS

[image]

**SPI interface** is specified to 50 MHz. However, there is a parameter in datasheet that isn't appearing in timing diagram, nor specified anywhere

tDACWAIT Sequential DAC update wait time  min. 1uS

According to my calculations (assuming 50 Mhz), timing diagram should be as follows

[image]

I have 1.65uS and I need 1uS :))

The question is about that tDACWAIT parameter, why to wait for?

1. Wait because of DAC analog circuitry needs to settle and in this case, I can ignore a little. While DAC settle, I can write a new value over SPI.
2. Wait because DAC analog still reads from digital section, faster will put other data and confuse output.
3. No idea, combination of above?

Thanks a lot for clarifications!

EDIT 1

To be more clear, this is how I plan to use it, not necessarily violate parameters, depends how I understand that tDACWAIT

[image]

Comment: The data sheet is very poor at explaining what it is. Good luck.

Comment: As you're looking to operate it outside its specifications, why worry about another one? Just buy a sample, thrash it, and see whether it runs. It may have a monostable in there to enforce SPI timing, in which case you're unlucky, it may simply be a typical propagation time of digital data through to analog in which case you're accepting the settling shortfall anyway. It may be something between the two that only shows up as corrupted performance at high temperature or low voltage, or even (horror of horrors) for some data values. Try it for your particular setup/voltage/temperature/data.